# How to determine the Docker image ID for a tag via Docker Hub API?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Given a tag `latest`, we want to find out another tag with the same image ID on Docker Hub.

Here is how to find out all tags for a repo with the Docker Hub API v2:

```
TOKEN=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${UNAME}'", "password": "'${UPASS}'"}' https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ | jq -r .token)
curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/fluent/fluentd/tags/?page_size=100 | jq
```

(See [gist.github.com/kizbitz](https://gist.github.com/kizbitz/175be06d0fbbb39bc9bfa6c0cb0d4721))

Unfortunately, it doesn't contain the image ID but always a `null` value for this key:

```
$ curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/fluent/fluentd/tags/?page_size=100 | jq
{
  "count": 36,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
...
    {
      "name": "v0.14.11",
      "full_size": 11964464,
      "id": 7084687,
      "repository": 219785,
      "creator": 2923,
      "last_updater": 2923,
      "last_updated": "2016-12-27T07:16:41.294807Z",
      "image_id": null,
      "v2": true,
      "platforms": [
        5
      ]
    },
...
```

Unfortunately, the image ID is something different than the `id` in the JSON above.

```
$ docker images | grep fluent
docker.io/fluent/fluentd                  v0.14.11            1441d57beff9        3 weeks ago         38.25 MB
```

Theoretically, it should be possible to access the Docker Manifests and along with the the image ID with this Docker Registry call but it doesn't help either:

```
$ curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/fluent/fluentd/manifests/latest"
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Name":"fluent/fluentd","Action":"pull"}]}]}
```

(See [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758258/is-that-possible-to-get-image-id-from-docker-registry-v2))

Here is a similar issue in the Docker GitHub repo but I still cannot figure out the solution: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1490 .

P.S.: Here is my Docker version with which I tried to push a test image:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-5.git037a2f5.fc25.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.7.4
 Git commit:      037a2f5/1.12.6
 Built:           Wed Jan 18 12:11:29 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Docker Registry API v2 uses image digest instead of image ID to distinguish image identity.

The image digest can be obtained from `docker-content-digest` of the HTTP response header by making the following API call:

```
$ REPOSITORY=fluent/fluentd

$ TOKEN=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$REPOSITORY:pull" | jq -r .token)

$ curl -s -D - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" https://index.docker.io/v2/$REPOSITORY/manifests/latest
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 1982
content-type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
docker-content-digest: sha256:eaea1edffc34cff3b5e31ee738ea56e46326f90731b4139a19948814a4f0a4db
docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
etag: "sha256:eaea1edffc34cff3b5e31ee738ea56e46326f90731b4139a19948814a4f0a4db"
date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 13:34:53 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
...
```

All tags can be obtained with the following API call:

```
$ curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://index.docker.io/v2/$REPOSITORY/tags/list
{"name":"fluent/fluentd","tags":["edge-onbuild","edge","jemalloc","latest-onbuild","latest","onbuild","stable-onbuild","stable","ubuntu-base","v0.12-latest-onbuild","v0.12-latest","v0.12-onbuild","v0.12.16","v0.12.18","v0.12.19","v0.12.20","v0.12.21","v0.12.23","v0.12.24","v0.12.26-2","v0.12.26-onbuild","v0.12.26","v0.12.27-onbuild","v0.12.27","v0.12.28-onbuild","v0.12.28","v0.12.29-onbuild","v0.12.29","v0.12.30-onbuild","v0.12.30","v0.12.31-onbuild","v0.12.31","v0.12","v0.14-latest-onbuild","v0.14-latest","v0.14-onbuild","v0.14.1","v0.14.10-onbuild","v0.14.10","v0.14.11-onbuild","v0.14.11","v0.14.2","v0.14.6","v0.14.8","v0.14"]}
```

Based on the above, to find the same digest as a specific tag, it will be a script like the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOSITORY=$1
TARGET_TAG=$2

# get authorization token
TOKEN=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$REPOSITORY:pull" | jq -r .token)

# find all tags
ALL_TAGS=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://index.docker.io/v2/$REPOSITORY/tags/list | jq -r .tags[])

# get image digest for target
TARGET_DIGEST=$(curl -s -D - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" https://index.docker.io/v2/$REPOSITORY/manifests/$TARGET_TAG | grep docker-content-digest | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

# for each tags
for tag in ${ALL_TAGS[@]}; do
  # get image digest
  digest=$(curl -s -D - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" https://index.docker.io/v2/$REPOSITORY/manifests/$tag | grep docker-content-digest | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

  # check digest
  if [[ $TARGET_DIGEST = $digest ]]; then
    echo "$tag $digest"
  fi
done
```

The result is as follows:

```
$ ./find_same_digest.sh fluent/fluentd latest
latest sha256:eaea1edffc34cff3b5e31ee738ea56e46326f90731b4139a19948814a4f0a4db
stable sha256:eaea1edffc34cff3b5e31ee738ea56e46326f90731b4139a19948814a4f0a4db
v0.12.31 sha256:eaea1edffc34cff3b5e31ee738ea56e46326f90731b4139a19948814a4f0a4db
v0.12 sha256:eaea1edffc34cff3b5e31ee738ea56e46326f90731b4139a19948814a4f0a4db
```

If you want to check the digest of the local image, you can get it with `docker images --digests`:

```
$ docker images --digests | grep fluentd
fluent/fluentd                  latest              sha256:eaea1edffc34cff3b5e31ee738ea56e46326f90731b4139a19948814a4f0a4db   1788ee7dcfcc        14 hours ago        35.41 MB
```

Comment: Minor note, since you only want the headers use `curl -I` to do a HTTP HEAD. Also, `-i` does the same thing as `-D -`.

Comment: Don't forget to specify `library/<reponame>` if needed.

Comment: You can speed up this code a fair bit by filtering out only the tags from `ALL_TAGS` that you care about instead of retrieving the digest for all of them.

Comment: For multiarch images, quite a trend nowadays, you would need to specify this content-type instead: `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json`

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is great! In addition, if you want to use this on a private repo, you need to add basic auth with your registry user credentials, and the additional scope parameter 'account='

(see http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/docker-registry-api-calls-as-an-authenticated-user)

Comment: `curl -u $UNAME:$UPASS "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$REPOSITORY:pull&account=$UNAME"`