# Double tagging docker images (latest + set version) + deploy latest to k8s + then lookup real tag?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to double tag docker images (latest + a version e.g. 1.3.0-78) at build/docker push time.

Then I want to deploy all my applications to kubernetes with the latest tag, if tests pass then look up the "real" tag (1.3.0-78) from the image digest I can get from kubernetes associated with the "latest", then create a manifest of all the docker tags as a release candidate.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a good way to find the "real" tag just based on a digest.

It appears you have to iterate all the tags in the entire repository and look for a matching digest.  Given there can be hundreds or thousands of tags for a specific image this could take a really long time.

Here is a script that finds all the tags that have the same digest, but it's very slow:

```
REPOSITORY=$1
TARGET_TAG=$2


# find all tags
ALL_TAGS=$(curl -s  $REPOSITORY/tags/list | jq -r .tags[])

# get image digest for target
TARGET_DIGEST=$(curl -s -D -  -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"   $REPOSITORY/manifests/$TARGET_TAG | grep Docker-Content-Digest | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

# for each tags
for tag in ${ALL_TAGS[@]}; do
  echo "checking tag ${tag}"
  # get image digest
  digest=$(curl -s -D -  -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" $REPOSITORY/manifests/$tag | grep Docker-Content-Digest | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

  # check digest
  if [[ $TARGET_DIGEST = $digest ]]; then
    echo "$tag $digest"
  fi
done
```

Does anyone have another approach?

Comment: It looks like you must have found this question already based on your code, but for anyone else searching, a more complete example of mapping digests to tags is shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808763/how-to-determine-the-docker-image-id-for-a-tag-via-docker-hub-api

Comment: Also, you can speed up that code a fair bit by applying a regex filter to the `ALL_TAGS` in order to only retrieve the digest of the of the tags that might be a match.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I want to deploy all my applications to kubernetes with the latest tag

No, you most certainly do not; you want to create what GitLab calls [an environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html#overview) using the release-candidate image, and then promote the RC into the real `Deployment` if all goes well. Using `:latest` is a recipe for disaster in almost all circumstances.

If you **insist** on using `:latest`, then I would suggest putting the "real" image tag in an annotation, label, or environment variable of the temporary `Deployment` so you will be able to acquire that information later, not only for your sanity but also make it available to the process that is presumably tearing down the temp stack and promoting the image to the production stack.

Comment: Using "latest" is simply for dev/qa convenience.  It's a common use case to want to dev and test with the most recent code.  The problem with latest is it's not reproducible, which is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I'm currently thinking that due to the limitations of the docker registry API, one way or another I'm going to have to publish docker tags to another system for lookup purposes :(  If I continue down the latest path, I'll have to publish to a parallel registry what the real tag is to another key/map system {latest: {digest: $digest, buildtag: $buildtag}}.

Comment: _Using "latest" is ... not reproducible_ yes, you and I are saying the same thing, but I must not be clearly communicating that one **never**, **ever** _needs_ to use `:latest` in any circumstance. That would be like saying "go checkout `master` and deploy whatever sha happens to be sitting in it" for "dev/qa convenience" -- it's not convenience, it's a lack of specificity. ... if you want to publish to a second repo, that's your choice, but you're solving the wrong problem.