# Dynamically get docker image id from its name

Tags: bash, docker

I need to dynamically delete all docker images in a server, except for the postgres image and container.

Now I need a dynamic way to get the id of that docker image so i will know to avoid it, using:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q | grep -v $<id_of_postgres_container>)
```

For the container part, i managed to find this:

```
docker ps -aqf "name=postgres"
```

which returns only the id of the postgres container. Is there any way to do the same with images without getting too deep into bash scripting?

or any better suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.ID}}" | 
grep "^postgres " | 
cut -d' ' -f2
```

Get docker images in the format `repository<space>id`, then filter lines starting with `postgres<space>`, then leave only id.

```
docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.ID}}" | 
grep "^postgres " | 
cut -d' ' -f2 | 
xargs docker rmi
```

But, if the postgres container and image is currently running or used, you can just:

```
 docker system prune --force --all
```

Answer (score 15):

You can just use:

```sh
$ docker images -q [image_name]
```

Where `image_name` can contain tags (appended after `:`), registry username with `/` (if applicable), etc.

The image has to be downloaded for this to work, for example:

```sh
$ docker pull hello-world
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
docker.io/library/hello-world:latest
$ docker images -q hello-world
d1165f221234
$ docker images -q hello-world:latest
d1165f221234
```

If the image is not locally available, the only alternative I can think of is to manually query the registry, e.g. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758258/is-that-possible-to-get-image-id-from-docker-registry-v2).

Answer (score 2):

`docker rmi` will never delete an image that corresponds to a running container.  So if you have a container based on `postgres` running, and you want to delete every other image on your system, the age-old incantations will do what you want; I’m too old-school for `docker system` but the “get all of the image IDs, then try to delete them all” I know is

```
docker images -q | xargs docker rmi
```

Which will print out some errors, but will delete all of the images it can.

Comment: (Reading this answer again, it also won’t delete images that correspond to stopped containers, though that’s less directly relevant to the question.)